# how to get a schematic diagram/layout of the an existing database

Tags: mysql, database-design, erd

I am looking for a schematic diagram of an existing database.
More precisely, I wan't to re-create the database model / schematics / the Entity Relationship Diagram (ERD) showing all the links between the tables of this existing database in MYSQL,I am using MYSQL workbench as an IDE,does it have database modelling tools to extract this?if not what other tools can do this?

UPDATE:

[image]

Comment: @RafaelPiccinelli - This is MYSQL database and am using MYSQL workbench IDE..I dont see such an optioin to create database diagram?which tool are you referring/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Reverse Engineer` under Database menu:

[image]

You just need to rearrange the tables.

Comment: I used that and it created a diagram for me,I see dotted lines and solid lines,where can I find the LEGEND on what these lines mean?I updated a screen shot of my diagram

Comment: Also,is there a way to save the diagram?

Comment: did you search for something before posting here? You can find a lot of videos on youtube, like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMxr5j83dcg

Comment: and those are your tables, you need to rearrange them ( I see now your update )

Comment: Can you expand on the "rearrange" part? why I need to rearrange?I am not changing anything in my datbase schema...any idea how to save this diagram?appreciate your inputs so far?

Comment: An `identifying relationship` is identified by a solid line between tables. A `non-identifying relationship` identified by a broken (dashed) line between tables. You can see more here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-relationship-tools.html

Comment: Got it...When I save it it's getting saved as .mwb file,Is there a way to save the EER diagram as a visio file or a type that can be shared between team members?saving as .mwb forces them to use mysql workbench

Comment: Please, you can google all these questions. Make a little search inside the manual. You can easily find all your answers. it's good to not extend a discussion in comments.